# SQL Server case statement altering value accuracy

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a fairly complicated SQL Server 2008 r2 sp2 query with this as one of the lines :-

```
      SUM((t.Quantity * contract.ValueOfOnePoint) * ((
        CASE contract.Style
                WHEN 3
                    THEN 1 / (1.0 + ((100.0 - Val) / 100.0 * 90.0 / 365.0))
                WHEN 2
                    THEN 1000 * (6.0 * (1.0 - (POWER((1.0 / (1.0 + ((100.0 - Val) / 200.0))), 20.0))) / ((100.0 - Val) / 200.0) + (100.0 * (POWER((1.0 / (1.0 + ((100.0 - Val) / 200.0))), 20.0))))
                END
            ) - (
            CASE contract.Style
                WHEN 3
                    THEN 1.0 / (1.0 + ((100.0 - t.Price) / 100.0 * 90.0 / 365.0))
                WHEN 2
                    THEN 1000 * (6.0 * (1.0 - (POWER((1.0 / (1.0 + ((100.0 - t.Price) / 200.0))), 20.0))) / ((100.00 - t.Price) / 200.00) + (100.0 * (POWER((1.0 / (1.0 + ((100.0 - t.Price) / 200.0))), 20.0))))
                END
            )
        )) AS NativeAmount
```

I am testing this on a single row which has a style of 3 so only the first line in the case statement should have any affect yet leaving the "WHEN 2" clause in it reduces the accuracy of the formula.

Eg. if I remove both WHEN 2 conditions I get an answer such 123.45678 but with the WHEN 2 line left in I get 123.46.  It seems to be rounding for some reason even though the second WHEN should never be in-play.

Any thoughts would be really appreciated - going mad!

Thanks.

James.

Comment: Instead of relying on math by `* some number.0`, why don't you use explicit `CAST` or `CONVERT` to indicate how many decimal places you want?

Comment: I think you may need to put a demo in SQLFiddle for this...

Comment: Yes, I suspect the data types of all of these columns will be important too.

Comment: What I don't get though is why the heck should it matter what is in the "WHEN 2" clause because that should not even be reached?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to combine two things.  The return type of the `case` statement is the same for all the `then` and `else` clauses.  This is a quote from the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx):

> [The case statement] returns the highest precedence type from the set of types in
>   result_expressions and the optional else_result_expression. For more
>   information, see Data Type Precedence (Transact-SQL).

So, the SQL Engine *does* care about all the clauses in the query (which is the answer to your question).

I don't fully understand what is happening in this case.  When you call the `power()` function, the compiler has to decide on the precision of the numeric value, based on the constants and column types.  Based on [this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f8351/1) SQL Fiddle, it chooses a precision of 38 and a scale of 1.  However, simple arithmetic on the values produces a precision of 36 and a scale of 23.  I'm not sure why, in the end, this results in rounding the value to two decimal places.  Perhaps the logic for assigning types for the `into` clause doesn't quite match the logic for typing of expressions.

Comment: Thank you Gordon (and others) for taking your time with your considered answers.  Gordon pointed me in the right direction and a simple CAST to a float over each WHEN clause resolved the issue. Thanks again guys.